# How to generate a price string with a currency symbol (e.g. $) instead of currency code (USD, EUR)?

Tags: android, kotlin, currency-formatting

This is my current code:

```
fun getMonthlyPriceString(yearlyPriceMicros: Long, currencyCode: String): String  {
    val format: NumberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()
    format.maximumFractionDigits = 2
    format.currency = Currency.getInstance(currencyCode)

    return format.format(yearlyPriceMicros.toFloat() / 1_000_000f / 12)
}
```

This produces: "SGD 5.00". However I want a price string like "$5.00" (with the symbol) instead.

The `currencyCode` argument is retrieved from an external API (RevenueCat) and is in the form "EUR", "USD", "SGD", etc.

I have tried replacing the code on line 4 with

```
format.currency = Currency.getInstance(Locale.getDefault())
```

But this produces: "£5.00" which is the wrong symbol (pounds) because I am based in Singapore and thus it should be "$5.00" (singapore dollars)

Comment: How will your user know whether $5.00 is SGD or USD?

Comment: @DavePile the native payment sheet for Android should confirm the payment currency. So this shouldn't be an issue. Most users would assume that the price is in their local currency as well.

Comment: If it were me, I would err on the side of caution- otherwise you find out how stupid people really are :) If you can't find a suitable API just create a function for the top  x currencies you expect to see and have the default return value for unforeseen currencies return the original currency code

Comment: @DavePile Understood. Thanks for the advice! I've release a few apps on iOS before with the same pricing format but it didn't seem like the users were confused. But it could also be that they just didn't report it :D I'll consider making it clearer for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I realised my language was set to "English (United Kingdom)" which was why the price was being displayed in pounds when using `format.currency = Currency.getInstance(Locale.getDefault())`. So changing my language to English (Singapore) fixed the issue.

However, I still wanted to display the currency based on the given currencyCode parameter in the function despite the default locale.

Thus, I managed to use the newer `NumberFormatter` api to achieve this:

```
fun getMonthlyPriceString(yearlyPriceMicros: Long, currencyCode: String): String {
    val monthlyPrice = yearlyPriceMicros.toFloat() / 1_000_000f / 12

    return NumberFormatter.with()
            .unit(Currency.getInstance(currencyCode)) // <-- Can pass the currency code from the function parameter here
            .precision(Precision.currency(Currency.CurrencyUsage.STANDARD)) // <-- This handles the decimal places for you
            .locale(Locale.getDefault()) // <-- Will still show the correct currency but in the user's locale
            .format(monthlyPrice)
            .toString()
}
```

Note that `NumberFormatter` is only available from **SDK Level 30** (Android 11) and above.